# What is the derivative of $\arccos(x^2)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I know that the derivative of arccos is: 
$-dx/\sqrt{1-x^2}$

So how would I find the derivative of $\arccos(x^2)$? What does the $-dx$ mean in the above formula?

Would it just be $-2x/\sqrt{1-x^2}$ ?

Comment: You quoted the derivative incorrectly. The derivative of $\arccos u$ with respect to $u$ is $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$. If you apply the chain rule you should end up with $\frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Using the chain rule, we can evaluate $\frac{d}{dx}\arccos (x^2)$.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\arccos(x^2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(x^2)^2}}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}\cdot 2x$$

Answer (score 3):

If you have a composite function $h(x)=(g\circ f)(x)$ then its derivative is given by $$h'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x).$$ (This is known as the Chain rule. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule for more information.)

In your case, $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\arccos x.$ Since $f'(x)=2x$ and $g'(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}},$ you can get the derivative just applying the Chain rule. (Note that $g'$ must be evaluated at $f(x)$ and not at $x.$)

Answer (score 1):

"$-dx$" should not be there.

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \arccos(x^2) = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-(x^2)^2}} \cdot \frac d {dx} x^2 = \frac{-2x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}.
$$